# Angular form: how can I dynamically get the value of radio buttons?

Tags: angular, forms, radio-button

I have two radio buttons. I need them to be able to grab the value of the selected one.

However, I'm always getting the value of the first radio button, even if the second one is selected.

This is what I have in my template:

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 pr-0">
    <div class="radio c-radio">
      <label class="text-bold fs-custom-11">
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="E"
          formControlName="radioIpunt"
          [disabled]="!actionBtns"

          checked
        /><span class="fa fa-circle"></span>YES</label
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 ph-0">
    <div class="radio c-radio">
      <label class="text-bold fs-custom-11">
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="M"
          formControlName="radioIpunt"
          [disabled]="!actionBtns"

        /><span class="fa fa-circle"></span>NO</label
      >
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is the form building in the .ts file:

```
constructor(// some props here not relevant for this question){
    this.forma = new FormGroup({
      /* a lot of controls not relevant to this question*/

      radioIpunt: new FormControl(''),
}
```

I'm trying the create a `request` object that contains the value of the controls of the form. I have no problem capturing all the other input values, but I can't properly capture the value of the radio inputs.
This is the logic I'm trying to apply:

```
buscaFolios() {  
     /* Some input value captures not relevant to this question */

        if(this.forma.controls.radioIpunt.value == 'M' ){
        console.log("M")
        this.requestDos.radioIpunt.value = 'SI'
        }
        else {
          console.log("E")
          this.requestDos.sindelectronico.value = 'NO'
        }
        this.requestDos.sindelectronico = this.forma.controls.radioIpunt.value;
        this.documentosService.buscaDocumentosTimbrados(this.requestDos).subscribe((res)=>{
         this.documentosTimbrados = res['documentos'])
        })
      }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks alright. But don't use `[disabled]` in template, instead disable the form control. Please provide a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz, that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using angular reactive forms it is not possible to get the first radio button value when second radio button is selected or vice versa.

Angular forms module uses formControlName property for all the form controls. For radio buttons in your case it is formControlName is same for both male and female. You will get the selected radio button value only. [Template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) might work in your case but I am not sure.